# it doesn't reflect to application navigator even though the files are in the right location [Sencha Architect]

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

My company is recently using 'Sencha Architect' for a project and

I've received the whole project being progressed by senior (the zip file was transferred through messenger).

but the problem is on my PC sencha architect doesn't show every files on the navigator tree.

only my 'Sencha Architect' doesn't show everything that I have as the screenshots

does any one have experience of same problem???????

I've checked all the directories and they exist in the right position as my senior's one.

I've checked 'app.js' as well and it contains view file which sench architect doesn't show on its navigator tree on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the metadata folder to be sure the files are there as well?